# Update Postgres Counter Cache with pure SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to add a counter cache to a database that has about 4 million rows. The normal way I would do this is in a migration like so:

```
class AddClicksCounterCacheToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :clicks_count, :integer
    Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :clicks) }
  end
end
```

However this is much too slow. [I came across a way](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/270-how-to-update-the-activerecord-counter-cache-magic-column) to do this in pure SQL but it looks like it was written for MySQL and I can't seem to get it to work for Postgres. Here's what I am trying:

```
class AddClicksCounterCacheToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :clicks_count, :integer
    execute <<-eos
      update posts, (select
                      id as post_id, coalesce(count, 0) as count
                    from posts left join
                      (select post_id, count(id) as count from clicks group by post_id) as count_table
                    on
                      posts.id = count_table.post_id) as count_table
      set
        posts.clicks_count = count_table.count
      where
        posts.id = count_table.post_id
    eos
  end
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

I'm pretty sure commas are allowed in postgres but to be honest I don't write too much raw postgres so I'm not sure.

Any idea how to convert this to Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Automated translation from MySQL to Postgres (without assessing of the correctness of the original query):

```
update posts
set posts.clicks_count = count_table.count
from (
    select id as post_id, coalesce(count, 0) as count
    from posts
    left join (
        select post_id, count(id) as count
        from clicks group by post_id) as count_table
    on posts.id = count_table.post_id) as count_table
where
    posts.id = count_table.post_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

With proper [`UPDATE` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) the same could look like this in Postgres:

```
UPDATE posts p
SET    clicks_count = ct.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT po.id, COALESCE(c.ct, 0) AS ct
   FROM   posts po
   LEFT   JOIN  (
      SELECT post_id, count(*) AS ct
      FROM   clicks
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) c ON c.post_id = po.id
   ) ct
WHERE  p.id = ct.id
AND    p.clicks_count <> ct.ct;  -- avoid empty update
```

I added another condition `AND p.clicks_count <> ct.ct` to avoid empty updates. Details:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

It might be faster to run these two queries instead:

```
UPDATE posts p
SET    clicks_count = p.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT post_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   clicks
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) ct
WHERE  p.id = p.category_id
AND    clicks_count <> p.ct;

UPDATE posts p
SET    clicks_count = 0
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM clicks WHERE post_id = p.id)
AND    p.clicks_count <> 0;
```

Comment: It seems you replaced the query with a new one during the grace period.